# What is this insect or worm?

Tags: species-identification

I found it on the cedar siding of my home in Houston, Texas.

It was quite small, I'd estimate 1cm in length. I did not observe it move up or down the side of the house, but when I touched it gently and it did bend over.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some species of *Eupithecia* perhaps. A type of moth, the larvae tend to resemble twigs. According to [this relatively old text](https://archive.org/stream/biostor-75172#page/n1), *Eupithecia miserulata* is the most commonly distributed species in Texas, but I'm sure identifications stem largely from expertise and adult specimens, both of which I lack. The larvae for E. miserulata don't seem to visually match what you have, there.

In essence, though, it's a caterpillar that will turn into a moth.

Comment: I looked up some images and it definitely looks similar, thank you. Quite a strange looking caterpillar